ValueError: Appended dtypes differ when appending two simple tables with dask
I am using Dask to write multiple very large dataframes to a single parquet dataset in python.
The dataframes are simple and all the column types are either floats or strings.
I iterate over the dask dataframes, and call to_parquet on each one, overwritting if this is the first dataframe, and appending if it is not.
ddf.to_parquet(options.output_prefix,
               append=True if n> 0 else False,
               engine="pyarrow",
               write_index=False,
               write_metadata_file=True,
               compute=True)

On the second call I get the following error:
ValueError: Appended dtypes differ.
{('IJC_SAMPLE_1', 'object'), ('riExonStart_0base', dtype('float64')), ('riExonEnd', 'float64'), ('PValue', dtype('float64')), ('IncLevelDifference', dtype('float64')), ('chr', 'object'), ('SkipFormLen', dtype('float64')), ('ID', 'float64'), ('SJC_SAMPLE_1', 'object'), ('geneSymbol', 'object'), ('ID.1', 'float64'), ('downstreamEE', dtype('float64')), ('downstreamES', 'float64'), ('strand', 'object'), ('SJC_SAMPLE_2',
'object'), ('upstreamES', dtype('float64')), ('IncFormLen', 'float64'), ('FDR', dtype('float64')), ('IJC_SAMPLE_2', 'object'), ('ID.1', dtype('float64')), ('downstreamES', dtype('float64')), ('FDR', 'float64'), ('IJC_SAMPLE_1', string[pyarrow]), ('GeneID', 'object'), ('IncFormLen', dtype('float64')), ('chr', string[pyarrow]), ('GeneID', string[pyarrow]), ('IncLevel1', 'object'), ('SJC_SAMPLE_1', string[pyarrow]), ('geneSymbol', string[pyarrow]), ('riExonStart_0base', 'float64'), ('PValue', 'float64'), ('upstreamEE', dtype('float64')), ('IncLevelDifference', 'float64'), ('IncLevel1', string[pyarrow]), ('strand', string[pyarrow]), ('SJC_SAMPLE_2', string[pyarrow]), ('IncLevel2', 'object'), ('SkipFormLen', 'float64'), ('riExonEnd', dtype('float64')), ('IncLevel2', string[pyarrow]), ('upstreamEE', 'float64'), ('downstreamEE', 'float64'), ('ID', dtype('float64')), ('IJC_SAMPLE_2', string[pyarrow]), ('upstreamES', 'float64')}

The dtypes of the first and second dataframes are the same:
dtypes for frame 0:
ID                            float64 
GeneID                string[pyarrow] 
geneSymbol            string[pyarrow] 
chr                   string[pyarrow] 
strand                string[pyarrow] 
riExonStart_0base             float64 
riExonEnd                     float64 
upstreamES                    float64 
upstreamEE                    float64 
downstreamES                  float64 
downstreamEE                  float64 
ID.1                          float64 
IJC_SAMPLE_1          string[pyarrow] 
SJC_SAMPLE_1          string[pyarrow] 
IJC_SAMPLE_2          string[pyarrow] 
SJC_SAMPLE_2          string[pyarrow] 
IncFormLen                    float64 
SkipFormLen                   float64 
PValue                        float64 
FDR                           float64 
IncLevel1             string[pyarrow] 
IncLevel2             string[pyarrow] 
IncLevelDifference            float64 
dtype: object

dtypes for frame 1:
ID                            float64 
GeneID                string[pyarrow] 
geneSymbol            string[pyarrow] 
chr                   string[pyarrow] 
strand                string[pyarrow] 
riExonStart_0base             float64 
riExonEnd                     float64 
upstreamES                    float64 
upstreamEE                    float64 
downstreamES                  float64 
downstreamEE                  float64 
ID.1                          float64 
IJC_SAMPLE_1          string[pyarrow] 
SJC_SAMPLE_1          string[pyarrow] 
IJC_SAMPLE_2          string[pyarrow] 
SJC_SAMPLE_2          string[pyarrow] 
IncFormLen                    float64 
SkipFormLen                   float64 
PValue                        float64 
FDR                           float64 
IncLevel1             string[pyarrow] 
IncLevel2             string[pyarrow] 
IncLevelDifference            float64 
dtype: object

If seems that the string[pyarrow] columns are being stored as object for the first time round, and then on the second time round, dask/pyarrow is seeing these as different dtypes. I've tried various things around the using the schema parameter to to_parquet, including setting all the string[pyarrow] columns to object or np.object_ or pa.from_numpy_dtype(np.object_) (unsupported) or enforcing storing them as "string[pyarrow]" (no effect).

Not sure about the dtype problem, but if Dataframes columns and dtypes are the same, maybe you should concat the Dataframes together before writing to Parquet in a single line of code?

@GuilaumeEB Each dataframe just about fits in memory, I wouldn't be able to concat them before writing to parquet. Unless there is some clever way of doing that with Dask.

Dask is lazy, so you can concat multiple Dataframes without reading them, and then call to_parquet on the bigger one. Dask should read the Dataframe chunk by chunk then.

@GuillaumeEB Unfortunately one of the things I do to the frames between loading and outputting them triggers the full frame to be loaded in memory.

What are you doing that needs the full DataFrame in memory?
